# Socket connection to my ip rather than 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

Well, i am at new at Socket programming in java. I tried to implement a simple socket program to send the message  with 127.0.0.1:4242 as localhost. But i want to send message to specific IP. How can i achieve that? Will it be possible to send message to my own IP as client-server running simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An endpoint in socket communications is an endpoint.  Anything you can do using 127.0.0.1 can be done using that machines ip address.  See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Every IP datagram has a *source address* and a *destination address* in the IP header, plus a transport protocol number, which is for majority of Internet traffic is either TCP or UDP. Then the header for that transport protocol lists *source and destination port numbers*.

So here you have it - sending, or better said "client", application gets assigned source address and port, usually automatically - address determined by the local routing table, port number assigned out of range of [ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), while "server" application *listens* on a [well known port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_known_port) bound to an address at a particular machine. This tuple `(source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port)` is enough for the datagram to get from here to there.

`127.0.0.1`, and actually all the addresses in the range `127/8`, are reserved for the [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback_address), a virtual local interface, i.e. it's the way to say "no matter what my real address is, or even if I don't have one, connect to *this* machine I'm at right now".

Read up on the [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) suite of protocols - it's a fairly simple concept (with ton of interesting details, of cource).